# Extract Source IP from log files

Tags: regex, awk, sed, extract

i want to extract "srcip=x.x.x.x" from log file in bash. my log file is like this:

```
2019:06:23-17:50:03 myhost ulogd[5692]: id="2021" severity="info" sys="SecureNet" sub="packetfilter" name="Packet dropped (GEOIP)" action="drop" fwrule="60019" initf="eth0" srcmac="3c:1e:04:92:6f:fb" dstmac="00:50:56:97:7c:af" srcip="185.53.91.50" dstip="192.168.50.10" proto="6" length="44" tos="0x00" prec="0x00" ttl="235" srcport="54522" dstport="5038" tcpflags="SYN"
```

I've wrote `awk '{print $15}'` to extract `srcip` but the problem is `srcip` position not same in each line. how can i extract `srcip=x.x.x.x` without position of that?

Comment: `grep -o 'script="[0-9.]*"'`

Comment: @Aaron: With a little change, it works: `grep -o 'srcip="[0-9.]*"'`

Comment: @Cyrus yeah, typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With any sed in any shell on every UNIX box:

```
$ sed -n 's/.*\(srcip="[^"]*"\).*/\1/p' file
srcip="185.53.91.50"
```

Comment: is it possible to this by windows PowerShell?

Comment: I've no idea, ask a new question and tag it with that.

Answer (score 0):

The following command provides the result you expect

`grep -o -P 'srcip="(\d{1,3}[.]){3}\d{1,3}"' log`

The option `o` is to print only the matched parts. The option `P` is to use perl-compatible regular expressions. The regex is matching `srcip=<ipv4>` and log is the name of the file you want to extract content from.

Here is a link to regex101 for an explanation for the regex: https://regex101.com/r/hjuZlM/2

Answer (score 0):

An `awk` version

```
awk -F"srcip=" '{split($2,a," ");print FS a[1]}' file
srcip="185.53.91.50"
```

Split the line using the key word, then get the next field after split.